# Update command using grid subform

Tags: .net, datagrid, subform

I'm putting together a simple list using a Telerik grid and a sub form (edit form?) to add or change data.  So far adding a new record works great: I set up the parameters, sent them to a stored procedure and the information is clearly being updated.  However when I do the nearly identical thing with the update command (adding only the id parameter of the table) it will only write the data if the current field is null.  Somehow I think this must be something simple I am missing.

I tested the update stored procedure and it works fine so I decided to add a sql statement to write the parameters to another table where I found that the parameters are not evidently coming from the edit form, at least not when there is any data in the field from the grid.  They instead are coming from the grid fields.

I'm using C# in Visual Studio with ASP.NET 3.5.  At the moment I have no code in the code behind and I was thinking maybe there has to be something for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across something I should have noticed the first time.  I had set conflict detection to "CompareAllValues", once I set it to "OverwriteChanges" it worked like a charm!

Duh.

Still no code behind, but I'm not sure yet if that's a good thing or not since I likely will need to do error handling.